# A loop $\alpha: I \rightarrow X$ is nulhomotopic $\iff$ $\alpha$ extends to a map $\alpha': D^2 \rightarrow X$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm looking to build the intuition as to why this is true. So, i'm viewing the map from $I$ to $X$ as a map from $S^1$ to $X$, and it sort of makes sense that in a simply connect space like $D^2$ every path is nulhomotopic, but still, I feel like something is missing from my understand of this. My professor did this proof without using the fundamental group, but he did go ham into euclidean geometry. Can anyone offer some insight into this for me? Thanks!

Comment: The cone with base $S^1$ is homeomorphic to $D^2$.

Comment: Hah, perfect. Thank you Lord Shark the Unknown.

Comment: Munkres does this proof very nicely--and rigorously (basically proving Shark's observation, and the picture tells the story) on p 349 of his "Topology."

Comment: How could I have missed this! My favorite textbook ever!